# Word processor that can work with HTML?

Tags: windows, html, wysiwyg, word-processor

I need to mimic the way Messenger boxes each message in bubbles.

[Word, obviously, is not a tool for this.](https://superuser.com/q/1275141/301042) However, going full-fledged HTML is kind of overkill for me. This is for a research article, so being able to focus on the content is pretty important to me. There is LaTeX, but it lacks aesthetics.

More importantly, as I think I can simply copy the HTML code from Messenger, an editor/word processor that can implement HTML will work. It's similar to how WordPress has both WYSIWYM and WYSIWYG panels.

What word processing tools that can work with HTML code?

I use Windows 10.

<sup>Related: [What word processing tools that can work with complicate text boxing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/102442/26474)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word processors are different from HTML editors.

Typically word processors are a kind of general-purpose software which you can compose letters, reports, even writing books can be done by word processors. They also provide extensive feature to format documents.
HTML editors are text-editors that can handle HTML files, and those are frequently used by web authors. It could be as simple as notepad to more sophisticated WYSIWYG-style like Dreamweaver.

For your case, you might to try KompoZer. If it still can't satisfy your requirement, you have to learn HTML (and CSS) yourself.

Comment: Isn't development of Kompozer stopped?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know another software that suit your need so you have to learn how to code using HTML and CSS...

Answer (score 2):

Another WYSIWYG HTML builder is BlueGriffon. Similar to Kompozer but I found it a little easier to use. BlueGriffon is still under development and the latest version was released in November, 2017. There are nice tutorials for both on the internet.